# Publishing messages on Azure Service Bus using MassTransit is intermittently slow

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit, .net-core-3.1, azure-servicebus-queues

This might not be a MassTransit question per se, but I'm trying to debug what's going on.

We are using MassTransit (`7.1.8`) with Azure Service Bus. Most of our messages are published just fine in a timely manner, but sometimes messages take a really long time to publish. And I don't understand why.

Our 4 (premium) ASB instances are under load, but CPU/Memory isn't above ~70% which I guess shouldn't be alarming.

Here's a snippet from our logs:

```
03 Jun 2021 13:41:55.642 IBusControl.PublishEvents() with 1 took 00:00:36.1610001
03 Jun 2021 13:41:55.642 SEND sb://<namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/events/...
03 Jun 2021 13:41:19.481 IBusControl.PublishEvents() called with 1 items.
```

And the corresponding code:

```
logger.LogDebug("IBusControl.PublishEvents() called with {count} items.", count);
var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var tasks = updatedItems.Select(x => bus.Publish<ISomeEvent>(new SomeEvent(x, x.Parameters)));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
stopWatch.Stop();
logger.LogDebug("IBusControl.PublishEvents() with {count} took {elapsed}", count, stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString());
```

So I'm trying to figure out why it takes >30 seconds between that we call `Publish` and when MassTransit logs the `SEND` entry.

Not really sure where to look? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

One interesting thing that I've noticed is that the time it takes is often around ~10 seconds, no matter how many messages there are to publish

[image]

Comment: Are you starting the bus before messages are published? Are you in the same data center, or are you publishing to US West from Australia (or the Moon)? I know for a fact on a P4 namespace I can [publish 6,000 messages/second](https://twitter.com/PhatBoyG/status/1382128095474372612) when in the same data center, much slower when further away from it:

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Both the ASB and the AppService publishing the messages are in the same region (North Europe)

Comment: @ChrisPatterson And it's an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project where we call `services.AddMassTransitHostedService(true);` in `ConfigureServices`

Comment: Then I'd delete the namespace and re-create it as you clearly got a bad host.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Interesting. Didn't know that was a thing you'd might need to do. Will be a sweaty afternoon  Appreciate the help though!

Comment: Hah, well you can open a support case with Microsoft, but in my experience, that's where you'll end up.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Yeah that's pretty much my experience dealing with Azure support as well

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Just a little follow up. I think I found the reason for the 10 second delay in the Azure Service Bus Event Log: "The request was terminated because the namespace <namespace> is being throttled. Error code : 50002. Please wait 10 seconds and try again". So I guess the Service Bus SDK used by MassTransit handles  that and retries after 10 seconds. I'm guessing the SDK would log that as well, so would it be possible to surface those logs in MassTransit so that I can confirm that that is actually what is going on?

Comment: So it was Azure Service Bus, I knew it. The SDK doesn't surface those retries to the calling application, which is why it isn't logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments above, Azure Service Bus was throttling the namespace, forcing the Azure SDK to fail and automatically retry the operation after a ten second delay.

> The request was terminated because the namespace  is being throttled. Error code : 50002. Please wait 10 seconds and try again

The failure and subsequent retry are handled entirely within the Azure SDK components, and not visible to MassTransit.